# How to format the command in order to write on serial port

Tags: c#, serial-port, protocols, communication, serial-communication

I have a card/rfid reader and I am trying to create a test application for it. I do have a protocol description document from the provider but I have never wrote serial port software before and everything looks so strange to me. I do have programming skils but a just do not know what I am doing wrong.

So, the model of the device is CRT288. In the spec doc I have the following data:

Baud rate (BPS): 9600

Communication type: Asynchronous communication

Transmit type: Half duplex

Bit detail: Start bit: 1 bit

Data bit: 8 bit

Parity bit: None

Stop bit: 1 bit

Start bit D0 D1 D2 D3 D4 D5 D6 D7 Stop sbit

Transmission Control Codes:

Code Value Meaning

STX 0x02 Start character of data package

ETX 0x03 End character of data package

ENQ 0x05 Sending require command (host -> reader)

ACK 0x06 Positive answer(reader-host)

NAK 0x15 Negative answer(reader-host)

EOT 0x04 Cancel communication

And most important (I believe) the data package  format of command:

STX(0x02) Command package ETX (0x03) BCC

BCC(Block check character) = STX ^ Command Package ^ ETX

(^ is exclusive OR calculation character)

For example: Reset command:

BCC=0x02 ^ 0x00 ^ 0x02 ^ 0x30 ^ 0x30 ^ 0x03

meaning (STX ^ MSL ^ CMD ^ CMP ^ SDT ^ ETX)

(1) MSL Length of sending text

(2)CMD Specifies a command.

(3)CMP Command Parameter.

(4)SDT Specifies the sending data, and has variable length(0~264bytes).

I have installed some doftware called Serial Port Monitor 4.0 (Eltima) and I am trying to send a command but it does not seem to work.

0x02 ^ 0x00 ^ 0x02 ^ 0x30 ^ 0x30 ^ 0x03 seems to be 11 or something.

Does anybody have a clue how to send a proper command using this specifications ?

On top of that, the reader ate one card, and I can not even reject teh card.
It is expcetcing a command for that :)

So if you guys have a simpel code sample in java or c# or how to properly format a command and send it to the rs232 please help me.

A

Comment: I'm voting to close this as *too localized*. You should consult the manual for whatever hardware you're working with.

Comment: I am looking at the manual, but there is no sofwtare example. I need a lien of code of how to write a command which is specified in teh manual like that: 0x02 ^ 0x00 ^ 0x02 ^ 0x30 ^ 0x30 ^ 0x03. I just choosed to write more details to make myself clear. Pelase do not close it because I really need som ehelp in here

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: The `^` xor operator is supported in C# just like in C and C++.  The only catch you're likely to run into is that C# bitwise operators do not preserve the type; often you need to cast the result from `int` back to `byte` or whatever other type you want.

Answer (score 1):

This general approach has worked for me in the past (Swipecard readers, Barcode readers, etc):

```
byte[] commandNameHere = { 0x02, 0x00, 0x02, 0x30, 0x30, 0x03 };

yourSerialPortObject.Write(commandNameHere, 0, commandNameHere.Length);
```

Comment: +1 for a good way to organize byte values into readable code